# error f0010 en python

Tags: python

hellos, como estan?. Tengo este codigo

```
a='20'
b="7"
c="Manolo"
print('Hola tengo {} años kiero en {} dias dominar este lenguaje. Me llamo {}'.format(a,b,c))
```

me da

> error f0010 error while code parsing: wrong or no encoding specified

T_T no entiendo k pasa T_T

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Python 2 o Python 3? ¿Qué IDE o editor usas?¿Codificación con la que guardas el .py?

Comment: ay virgen a ver si te puedo contestar, uso python 3.6.5, visual code studio y lo de codificacion con la que guardo el .py, de eso no tengo ni idea xD

Comment: Estoy tomando un curso por video de python, el instructor usa el pycharm, yo estoy usando el visual studio code, pero, ahora me baje el pycharm entre el codigo exactamente como lo puse mas arriba y todo bien.... k rayos pasa T_T